# how to insert TOC in word document using docx4j in java

Tags: java, docx4j

I have one word document that consist one index. In that index, the content is the table of content and that content are hyperlinks also with page number. When I click on any hyperlinks, the cursor goes to that page where that heading exist.

Like following:

```
1 Introduction.......................................1
1.1 about us........................................1
2 reference.........................................3
```

I want to insert one more heading after introduction.

Answer (score 0):

With forthcoming v3.3.0, you can ask docx4j to update your TOC; see [TocUpdateDemo.java](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/VERSION_3_3_0/src/samples/docx4j/org/docx4j/samples/TocUpdateDemo.java)

Answer (score 0):

Visit http://blog.iprofs.nl/2012/10/22/adding-images-and-layout-to-your-docx4j-generated-word-documents-part-1/#comment-34262 . It helps me a lot.
I suggest that, firstly add heading and after that update table of content using following code:

```
     wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart()
    .getDocumentSettingsPart().getJaxbElement()
    .setUpdateFields(new BooleanDefaultTrue());
```